# How can input coordinate be inserted in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose I have 3 coordinate a(1,2),b(3,4) and c(5,6).

> How can I insert them using a 'input' function so that the user can enter the coordinates and save the input coordinate into a matrix form.

eg A = input(......);

A = [1,2;3,4;5,6]

Answer (score 0):

If you want a one line input, you can do this

```
                            % // a string ('s') is expected as input;
                            % // it'll be parsed expecting 6 
                            % // real numbers space separated
  A = sscanf( input('','s'), '%f %f %f %f %f %f' );
```

and you may want to do a `reshape`

```
  A = reshape(A,2,[])';
```

Example

```
 % // {Keyboard input}: 
        1 2 3 4 5 6

 % // returned value

A =
 1     2
 3     4
 5     6
```

Comment: Hmm I see...so that will be one of the way...thanks a lot ya Acorbe =)